# How much code can I post in a question/answer?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering how much code is appropriate to post into a question/answer. By how much I mean how many lines. Is there a limit? Should I just post what I consider long code in pastebin/co and than just have a link?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55986/238438 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25624/238438

Comment: related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/how-to-ask-scripting-questions-efficiently?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an answer comes up with a full module in one file I think up to 200 lines of code should be OK (not as a hard limit).

If the code is distributed to more than two files or exceeds a few hundred lines I would suggest to upload it to a service like:

- [github gists](https://gist.github.com/)
- [pasteall](http://pasteall.org/)
- [bpaste](http://bpaste.net/)

In a question it should be enough to point out the parts that cause trouble or about the correct usage of the API (roughly max 50 LoC), a supplementary .blend file (or addon .zip) could be added.

Comment: @iKlsR Thanks for the edit, since we have this expiring problem with .blend files I didn't suggest pasteall and really hoped that code could be placed on a more persistent location. Do you think that the process of registering would be to much an additional obstacle?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem and Pasteall snippets are persistent I think.